# How to restrain keypress/keyup/keydown action and execute only if ajax call is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a barcode scanner gun which scans very fast. Since barcode scanner is treated like a keyboard action, there are times when I fire the gun twice consecutively, the textbox would not stop itself from entering values on it (even though the gun automatically fires an enter command keycode 13 after entering all the scanned values).

Here is my code:

```
$('#sku_upc_input').keyup(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    switch (code) {
        case 13:
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
            break;
    }
 });
```

So on submission, it would fire an ajax.

```
$('#add_scans_sku_form').submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/netsuite/po/checkUPCSkipCapture/',
        data: {
            po_num: current_po.id,
            upc_code: $('#upcCode').val(),
            sku_id: sku_id
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['status'] != false) {
               initUPCPopup(sku_id, desc);
            } else {
               $('#sku_upc_input').val('');
               $('#sku_upc_input').focus();
            }
        }
     });
)};
```

I did a solution that after keycode 13 (enter), the textbox would disable itself so the gun won't enter extra values (if fired again immediately) on the textbox but another flaw of this is that sometimes, when you fire the gun fast consecutively, the textbox that receives the scanned value would input incomplete values lets say for example. If the barcode is WORAS012-Z it would sometimes be RAS012-Z or even S012-Z.

The gun's action is so fast that it's hard to perfectly get a complete value in it when fired consecutively. I hope my problem is understood. I hope there are solutions to this. Please give me some ideas. Thank you!

Comment: as per your title ...if you want "a piece of code" to execute only when ajax call is finished then write that in "complete" of ajax . I hope you must be knowing how to write "complete" in ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scanner to only scan once the ajax call is complete you should set a variable to know whether it has been completed or not.

```
var completed = true; //<<<<< define the variable

$('#sku_upc_input').keyup(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    switch (code) {
        case 13:
            if ( !completed ) return; //<<<<< cancel action if it's not completed yet
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
            break;
    }
 });

 $('#add_scans_sku_form').submit(function (e) {
    completed = false; //<<<<< set to false when fired
    $.ajax({
        url: '/netsuite/po/checkUPCSkipCapture/',
        data: {
            po_num: current_po.id,
            upc_code: $('#upcCode').val(),
            sku_id: sku_id
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            completed = true //<<<<< set back to true when complete
            if (data['status'] != false) {
               initUPCPopup(sku_id, desc);
            } else {
               $('#sku_upc_input').val('');
               $('#sku_upc_input').focus();
            }
        }
     });
)};
```

I'm not sure what kind of scanner that is or how it works, but based on what you said I think a better approach would be to cancel everything for 200-500ms and not based on how fast your ajax call is like so:

```
var completed = true;

// at the start of your event handler
if ( !completed ) return;
completed = false;
setTimeout(function(){
    completed = true;
},200)
```